# matplotlib: setting xticklabels returned some "help" output

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a dozen **boxplots** on the same plot, arranged **horizontally**. I want the spacing between them to be constant, so I didn't set `positions` when calling `plt.boxplot()`.

For each boxplot, I want the corresponding **label** on the **X-axis** to have a certain value.
I do this:

```
xtickNames = plt.setp(ax, xticklabels=[str(v) for v in values])
plt.setp(xtickNames)
```

It works, but I get all this stuff output on screen:

> agg_filter: unknown   alpha: float (0.0 transparent through 1.0
>   opaque)            animated: [True | False]            axes: an
>   :class:`~matplotlib.axes.Axes` instance            backgroundcolor:
>   any matplotlib color            bbox: rectangle prop dict
>   clip_box: a :class:`matplotlib.transforms.Bbox` instance
>   clip_on: [True | False]            clip_path: [
>   (:class:`~matplotlib.path.Path`,
>   :class:`~matplotlib.transforms.Transform`) |
>   :class:`~matplotlib.patches.Patch` | None ]            color: any
>   matplotlib color            contains: a callable function
>   family or fontfamily or fontname or name: [FONTNAME | 'serif' |
>   'sans-serif' | 'cursive' | 'fantasy' |                   'monospace' ]
>   figure: a :class:`matplotlib.figure.Figure` instance
>   fontproperties or font_properties: a
>   :class:`matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` instance
>   gid: an id string            horizontalalignment or ha: [ 'center' |
>   'right' | 'left' ]            label: string or anything printable with
>   '%s' conversion.            linespacing: float (multiple of font size)
>   lod: [True | False]            multialignment: ['left' | 'right' |
>   'center' ]            path_effects: unknown   picker:
>   [None|float|boolean|callable]            position: (x,y)
>   rasterized: [True | False | None]            rotation: [ angle in
>   degrees | 'vertical' | 'horizontal' ]            rotation_mode:
>   unknown   size or fontsize: [size in points | 'xx-small' | 'x-small' |
>   'small' |                   'medium' | 'large' | 'x-large' |
>   'xx-large' ]            sketch_params: unknown   snap: unknown
>   stretch or fontstretch: [a numeric value in range 0-1000 |
>   'ultra-condensed' |                   'extra-condensed' | 'condensed'
>   | 'semi-condensed' |                   'normal' | 'semi-expanded' |
>   'expanded' | 'extra-expanded' |                   'ultra-expanded' ]
>   style or fontstyle: [ 'normal' | 'italic' | 'oblique']
>   text: string or anything printable with '%s' conversion.
>   transform: :class:`~matplotlib.transforms.Transform` instance
>   url: a url string            variant or fontvariant: [ 'normal' |
>   'small-caps' ]            verticalalignment or va or ma: [ 'center' |
>   'top' | 'bottom' | 'baseline' ]            visible: [True | False]
>   weight or fontweight: [a numeric value in range 0-1000 | 'ultralight'
>   | 'light' |                   'normal' | 'regular' | 'book' | 'medium'
>   | 'roman' |                   'semibold' | 'demibold' | 'demi' |
>   'bold' | 'heavy' |                   'extra bold' | 'black' ]
>   x: float            y: float            zorder: any number

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xtickNames = plt.setp(ax, xticklabels=[str(v) for v in values])
```

sets the `xticklabels` property.

```
plt.setp(xtickNames)
```

prints the configurable properties of `xtickNames` to the screen.

So just use the first command to set the `xticklabels` without printing to the screen. Alternatively, you could use

```
ax.set_xticklabels(map(str, values))
```

Comment: So I don't even need to save  to a variable the output of that first line, right?